# How to find if an inputted double is a multiple of 0.05

Tags: c++, int, double, modulus

I have an assignment where I need to check if a double that some user inputs is a multiple of 0.05.

For example, if they enter 1.96, they will get an error. But if they enter 1.95, then it will proceed to the next step.

I tried doing different thinks like

```
double price;
cin >> price;
int multiple = ((int)(price * 100)) % 5;


if (multiple == 0)
{
    cout << "This is a multiple of 0.05" << endl;
}
else if (multiple != 0)
{
    cout << "No multiple" << endl;
}
```

Is there any way to have this done? And the price needs to be a double. As the assignment I am doing is a vending machine project that takes coins and returns change.

Comment: Why do you multiply and mod 5 _twice_?

Comment: Do you mean for the if else statements? One of them is to see if the number is a multiple, the other is the opposite.

Comment: isn't `if (multiple == 0)` sufficient?

Comment: I dont know where my head is... It should be yes.

Comment: You don't need to check for !=0 in the else. It is pretty much guaranteed.

Comment: I need to read a C++ for beginners book again... I dont know what I am doing... Unfortunately none of these solve my original problem.

Comment: I assume you are being bitten by a precision error where the format for a double doesn't allow a value that is exactly what you are entering. You need to make sure you round your value up when you convert to an int.

Comment: Btw, since you work with coins, the smallest possible value is 1 cent, so you don't have to work with double, but with an integer that will keep the value in cents (if it will make your life easier).

Comment: The requirement you mention does not imply that you need `double`. One of the points of this type of assignment is discovering that floating point is no good for this kind of problem, and that you need figure out a way to work with integers instead.

Comment: Extracting the fraction part, multiplying by `100.` and then rounding will work for larger `price`s. `double iptr; int multiple = static_cast<int>(std::round(std::modf(price, &iptr)*100.)) % 5;` could p

Comment: Ask these kinds of Questions and Homework related on Code Review website.

Answer (score 3):

Standard library has the `fmod` function for floating point modulo (`remainder` isn't as useful as it doesn't guarantee the same sign as the numerator operand).

You have to consider however, that `0.05` is not representable in binary floating point. Therefore the meaning of "multiple of 0.05" in real math is crucially different, than the meaning of "multiple of the floating point value that is the closest representable value to 0.05".

Given that the input of the calculation contains some error, that error will increase upon floating point operations on those inputs. It is completely possible that even if 0.05 * x = y is true in real math, doesn't necessarily mean that holds true in floating point math.

As such, it rarely makes sense to compare floating point calculation results with a single value. This holds true to comparing the remainder to zero. What makes sense is to compare to some relative threshold, which is assumed to be greater than the accumulated error of the calculation. Since you're presumably dealing with quantized values down to one hundredth (as is common with currency), a sensible threshold is half of the quantization resolution.

```
double quantum = 0.01;
double threshold = quantum / 2;
bool is_multiple = std::fmod(price, 0.05) < threshold;
```

Comment: This solution will fail for cases in which the value of price is just below a multiple of 0.05 (for example, price = 0.0999..).

Answer (score 0):

Remember, your doubles are being stored as binary values, which do not convert exactly between decimal and binary.

You are better off working with the character string.

First check that the entered values has the format "*.NN".  If so check if the second N after the decimal point is 0 or 5.

Comment: The poster has indicated that using a double is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
double price;
cin >> price;
int multiple = (int)(price * 100) % 5 == 0 && (int)(price * 100) != 0 && (price -(double)(int)(price * 100) / 100) == 0;


if (multiple == 0)
{
    cout << "This is a multiple of 0.05" << endl;
}
else if (multiple != 0)
{
    cout << "No multiple" << endl;
}
```